# Universal Windows Application - Accessibility is not working for Canvas

Tags: canvas, uwp, accessibility, windows-10-universal, narrator

```
<Grid Name="Simple Grid" >
    <Button AutomationProperties.Name="Simple Button" Name="Button" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Control" AutomationProperties.HelpText="Help text for the button is set from XAML" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="285,228,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Canvas AutomationProperties.Name="Simple Border" IsTapEnabled="True" Background="Black" Height="300" IsAccessKeyScope="True" Width="200" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Control" AutomationProperties.HelpText="Help text for the border is set from XAML" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
</Grid>
```

In the above code in Universal Windows Application, Accessibility testing using "Narrator" is working for Button and that was not working for Canvas. Similarly its not working for the Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls like Border, Image..

How to achieve the accessibility of these controls?

Comment: I replied this on MSDN. If you can accept the workaround I will also post it here.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have replied with some details in MSDN. Can you please check and update me?